# How to solve error "cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time"

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust. Here is a piece of code for computer stock transaction. The Strategy will buy some stocks when the `SignalTrigger` triggers, and sell those stocks if after 30s/90s in different way. The code can't be compiled. Here is the code:

```
use std::cmp;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::process;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Depth {
    ts: u32,
    ap_vec: Vec<f64>,
    bp_vec: Vec<f64>,
    av_vec: Vec<u32>,
    bv_vec: Vec<u32>,
}


struct Order {
    ts: u32,
    id: u32,
    is_buy: bool,
    is_mkt: bool,
    vol: u32,
    price: f64,
}

struct LongPosition {
    vol_left: u32,
    ts: u32,
}

struct Strategy {
    order_id: u32,
    prev_buy_ts: u32,
    map_orderid_position: BTreeMap<u32, LongPosition>, // map<order_id, volume_left>
}

impl Strategy {
    fn on_depth(&mut self, depth: &Depth) -> Vec<Order> {
        let mut orders_vec: Vec<Order> = Vec::new();
        for (order_id, long_position) in &mut self.map_orderid_position {
            if depth.ts - long_position.ts > 90 * 1000 {
                let order = self.make_order(depth.ts, false, true, long_position.vol_left, 0.0);
                orders_vec.push(order);
            } else if depth.ts - long_position.ts > 60 * 1000 {
                let order = self.make_order(depth.ts,false,true,long_position.vol_left,depth.bp_vec[0]);
                orders_vec.push(order);
            }
        }
        return orders_vec;
    }

    fn make_order(&mut self, ts: u32, is_buy: bool, is_mkt: bool, vol: u32, price: f64) -> Order {
        let order = Order {
            id: self.order_id,
            ts,
            is_buy,
            is_mkt,
            vol,
            price,
        };
        self.order_id = self.order_id + 1;
        return order;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let empty_price_vec: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
    let map_orderid_position: BTreeMap<u32, LongPosition> = BTreeMap::new();
    let mut strategy = Strategy {
        prev_buy_ts: 0,
        order_id: 0,
        map_orderid_position: map_orderid_position,
    };
}
```

The compile says:(I have comment line 88 and line 90 in the snippet)

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:46:29
   |
44 |         for (order_id, long_position) in &mut self.map_orderid_position {
   |                                          ------------------------------
   |                                          |
   |                                          first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                          first borrow later used here
45 |             if depth.ts - long_position.ts > 90 * 1000 {
46 |                 let order = self.make_order(depth.ts, false, true, long_position.vol_left, 0.0);
   |                             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:49:29
   |
44 |         for (order_id, long_position) in &mut self.map_orderid_position {
   |                                          ------------------------------
   |                                          |
   |                                          first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                          first borrow later used here
...
49 |                 let order = self.make_order(depth.ts,false,true,long_position.vol_left,depth.bp_vec[0]);
   |                             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 12 warnings emitted

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `greeting`
```

I am a little confused about Rust, snippets like these are really common in other languages. Can you make an explanation and tell me how to fix(avoid) this situation?

Comment: Could you mark the lines? No one wants to count

Comment: Here is the MRE code. Just cargo run it. Nothing to be installed. @trentcl

Comment: Relevant blog post: [Interprocedural conflicts by Niko Matsakis](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/11/01/after-nll-interprocedural-conflicts/).

Comment: @YNC: if trentcl says that, it's because there is many useless stuff in your code (concerning your question), and it can discourage people to help you

Comment: @yolenoyer Yeah, I deleted them, now the code is simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are borrowing the whole instance when you are calling `self.make_order`. The compiler cant be sure that you are not going the change `map_orderid_position`. Instead, you can create a standalone function and pass the mutable reference to `order_id` field to it.

```rust
impl Strategy {
    fn on_depth(&mut self, depth: &Depth) -> Vec<Order> {
        let mut orders_vec: Vec<Order> = Vec::new();
        for (order_id, long_position) in &mut self.map_orderid_position {
            if depth.ts - long_position.ts > 90 * 1000 {
                let order = make_order(depth.ts, false, true, long_position.vol_left, 0.0, &mut self.order_id);
                orders_vec.push(order);
            } else if depth.ts - long_position.ts > 60 * 1000 {
                let order = make_order(depth.ts,false,true,long_position.vol_left,depth.bp_vec[0], &mut self.order_id);
                orders_vec.push(order);
            }
        }
        return orders_vec;
    }

    
}

fn make_order(ts: u32, is_buy: bool, is_mkt: bool, vol: u32, price: f64, order_id: &mut u32) -> Order {
    let order = Order {
        id: *order_id,
        ts,
        is_buy,
        is_mkt,
        vol,
        price,
    };
    *order_id += 1;
    return order;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of updating `self.order_id` in the function `make_order()` you can update it in the function `on_depth()`. Then you don't have to use `&mut self` for `make_order()` and the problem is solved.

Example:

```
impl Strategy {
    fn on_depth(&mut self, depth: &Depth) -> Vec<Order> {
        let mut orders_vec: Vec<Order> = Vec::new();
        for (order_id, long_position) in &self.map_orderid_position {
            let order = if depth.ts - long_position.ts > 90 * 1000 {
                self.make_order(depth.ts, false, true, long_position.vol_left, 0.0)
            } else if depth.ts - long_position.ts > 60 * 1000 {
                self.make_order(depth.ts, false, true, long_position.vol_left, depth.bp_vec[0])
            } else {
                continue;
            };
            orders_vec.push(order);
            self.order_id += 1; // Update `self.order_id` here
        }
        return orders_vec;
    }

    // Changed `&mut self` to `&self`
    fn make_order(&self, ts: u32, is_buy: bool, is_mkt: bool, vol: u32, price: f64) -> Order {
        let order = Order {
            id: self.order_id,
            ts,
            is_buy,
            is_mkt,
            vol,
            price,
        };
        // Removed `self.order_id = self.order_id + 1`
        return order;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html):

> The benefit of having this restriction is that Rust can prevent data
> races at compile time. A data race is similar to a race condition and
> happens when these three behaviors occur:
>
> ```
> Two or more pointers access the same data at the same time.
> At least one of the pointers is being used to write to the data.
> There’s no mechanism being used to synchronize access to the data.
> ```
>
> Data races cause undefined behavior and can be difficult to diagnose
> and fix when you’re trying to track them down at runtime; Rust
> prevents this problem from happening because it won’t even compile
> code with data races!

I don't know what the best practice is but I would generally make a clone of the variable for **reading**, for, example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");

    let r1 = s.clone();   // if this was &mut s, I'll get the same error
    let r2 = &mut s;

    println!("{}, {}", r1, r2);
}
```

So, you could probably try making clone of `self.map_orderid_position` since you are just reading values from it.